# ls -ld list files inside a folder which is having only execute permission

Tags: linux, permissions

In Linux, I gave only `execute` permission to a directory named `test`.

after switching to the directory `test`, when I run `ls -ld` it was showing some hidden files.

Please explain this.

Comment: You might have an alias for `ls`.

Comment: Please add the output of `getfacl test` or (if that is nor available) `ls -ld test`.

Comment: You did give it 111 (execute-only for everyone) perms so that no one, not even yourself, can see the files?  If you give it, say, 711 (you have full perms, others have execute/enter only perms) perms, ls will still be able to see the files if you own the directory or if you are root.

Comment: which *some* hidden files?

Answer (score 1):

This should be the expected behaviour:

```
michas@lenny:~$ mkdir test
michas@lenny:~$ chmod a=x test
michas@lenny:~$ ls -ld test
d--x--x--x 1 michas users 0 Mar  3 07:56 test
michas@lenny:~$ cd test
michas@lenny:~/test$ ls -ld
d--x--x--x 1 michas users 0 Mar  3 07:56 .
michas@lenny:~/test$ ls -la
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
```

If your `ls` is doing something different, have a look at `type ls` to see how `ls` is defined in your case.

Explaination:

If you do not specify a directory explicitly `ls` will list the current directory written as `.` in Unix. It normally will list the *content* of the directory, which requires read permissions on the directory. With the `-d` option `ls` will instead show the directory *itself*, which does only require read permissions in the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
# ls - list directory contents

# ls -d --directory
```

list  directory entries instead of contents, and do not derefer  ence symbolic links

```
# ls -h  --human-readable
```

with -l, print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)

```
# ls -ld - The GNU linker
```

ld combines a number of object and archive files, relocates their data and ties up symbol references. Usually the last step in compiling a program is to run ld

Know more options using

```
# man ls
```

Navigate to home directory and check for the alias if u have setted 
ny editing the file .bash and search for /alias

```
# vim .bash
```

Changing a Directory permission using chmod 777 or Chmod -R 777 or any other permission own't show the hidden file's it might issue with you manually added alias